# Need help coding iterator for a circular linked list in C++

Tags: c++, listiterator

So I'm creating a circular linked list to solve the Josephus Problem for an assignment. I had a really bad professor for my C++ class and I don't really know how to do anything in C++. I'm trying to code an iterator to transverse the list, but I have no clue where to start or how to implement it. Can anyone give me an suggestions or advice on how to start coding this?

Comment: This is not a chatroom or discussion board; we don't give "suggestions or advice". It is a Q&A repository. Please post a concrete, specific question about a piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much just like the `std::list` iterator, except the end iterator is where the next pointer is the head of the list, not when it's `NULL`.  A reference page will tell you what you're supposed to implement.  The underlying representation will be a pointer to a list node, `operator*` will return a reference to the data, `operator++` will set the pointer to `next`, etc.

Alternatively, use an array implementation with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Josephus problem is if N people have decided to elect a leader by arranging
themselves in a circle and eliminating every Mth person around the circle, closing ranks as each person drops out. Find which person will be the last one remaining.
Here is a very simple implementation of this problem in C++.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct node
    {   int info;
        struct node *next;
    }arr[]={{rand(),arr+1},{rand(),arr+2},{rand(),arr+3},{rand(),arr+4},{30,arr}};
    typedef struct node* Node;
    void josephus(Node);
    int main()
    {
        josephus(arr);
        system("pause");
    }
    void josephus(Node head)
    {
        Node ptr,temp;
        int length=1,position,i;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr->next!=head)
        {
           ptr=ptr->next;
           length++;
        }
        ptr=head;
        printf(" Enter the position at which element should get eliminated ");
        scanf("%d",&position);
        while(length>1)
        {
           i=1;
           while(i<position)
           {
               ptr=ptr->next;
               i++;
           }
           temp=ptr;
           ptr=ptr->next;
           free(temp);
           length--;
        }
         printf("\n Last Element Left is %d Its address is %u \n",ptr->info,ptr);
        }
```

For more details visit-
https://github.com/SahdevKansal02/Data-Structures-And-Algorithms.git